# WifIManager.initialize doesn't exist after 4.1.2, so what should I replace it with?

Tags: java, android, networking, wifi

First post. I've been looking at an app which is built for 4.1.2 and i'm trying to make it work on 4.2.2 or above. Now, in 4.1.2, an essential part of WiFi is to call this initialize method. Unfortunately, this method doesn't exist after 4.1.2, so won't work.

```
wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
channel = wifiManager.initialize(context, context.getMainLooper(), null);
connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

It is line 2, channel = wifiManager.initialize(context, context.getMainLooper(), null); that causes the issues on later versions of Android, effectively you get a NoSuchMethod exception. I'm looking for an equivalent replacement or how I should go about fixing this. Removing it breaks the software :(

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find the initialize method in any of the older version's android documentation for the WifiManager. I did find a similar method, with the same variables in the WifiP2pManager. I found some sample source at: http://www.codota.com/android/scenarios/52c5d1e6da0a43cec2a25272/android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager?tag=coyote

Here's the code fragment from that site:

```
mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
```

The javadoc for the WifiP2pManageris located at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It does exist in version 4.1.2, and the software runs perfectly on it. Here is a link to the grepCode:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java#WifiManager.initialize%28android.content.Context%2Candroid.os.Looper%2Candroid.net.wifi.WifiManager.ChannelListener%29

Comment: I was looking at Android's official API (set to API level 16) and I didn't see the method. I used: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

Comment: OK, Do you have any idea how I can go about sorting it? :(

Comment: What do you mean by sorting it?

Comment: Well I need to replace that function/method with a newer one, or make the necessary changes so it will work on later than just 4.1.2.

Comment: I think my suggestion to use the WifiP2pManager should do what you want. It looks like Google just split the WifiManager up into smaller managers. What exactly is the code trying to do?

Comment: I'll try WiFiP2PManager. It's just initializing the wifi before running the app I believe. I'm still reading up on it. I was given this code without any documentation etc.